# Eclipse plugin: Persistent markers not persisting

Tags: eclipse-plugin, markers, eclipse-pde

I've developed a quick and simple plugin that adds line markers for lines containing the text "TODO", based on the "Plugin with an incremental project builder" template.

It works, but markers are *not* persisted between Eclipse sessions (restarts).

I have the following element in my plugin.xml:

```
<extension
     id="todoTask"
     name="TODO Task"
     point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
  <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.taskmarker">
  </super>
  <persistent value="true"/>
</extension>
```

Again, the plugin works fine, so this is processed, but it doesn't seem to matter if I set the `persistent value` attribute to `true` or `false`, it just doesn't persist the markers.

Why aren't the markers persisted and how can I fix this? Do I need to perform additional programming/configuration to persist them? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was through trial and error. The marker id needs to have a dot in it in order to actual be counted as a marker type. So in your case try setting `id="todoTask.marker"` for example and then calling `someResource.createMarker("todoTask.marker")`. Oh, and maybe write the id with lower case letters, just to be on the safe side